# Magento 1.9 Session Files clearing

Tags: php, ubuntu, magento, magento-1.9

Hi I currently have a magento 1.9 site which i use session storage as files as i find that using the database is very slow.

I currently have about 16 gig of session files which i want to delete.

If I run:

find . -name 'sess*' -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;

The site grinds to a halt and then kills the database attached.

I then looked at garbage collection I changed:

session.gc_probability = 1 
session.gc_divisor = 100

When I did this and restarted apache the site crashed too?

What would be the best way to remove these files?

Comment: just remove them at a time when the site does not have many visitors with rm -rf var/session. This will logout everyone from the website though, customers and admins.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the whole folder, from your Magento Root with the following

```sh
rm -rf var/session/*
```

Also, if you have enought RAM, you should consider using Redis to store session. [Here is a nice tuto for Magento 1](https://inchoo.net/magento/using-redis-cache-backend-and-session-storage-in-magento/).

Answer (score 0):

first go to the `var/session` folder of the magento root directory

```
find . -name "*" -print | xargs rm -rf
```

This command will delete all the data in the current folder without prompting you.